# terraform is giving error Invalid value for module argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Vpc.tf in vpc module

```
  resource "random_id" "generic" {
    
      byte_length = 32
      prefix= "${var.vpc_name}-"
    }

 
 resource "aws_vpc" "main"{

     cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr_block
     tags= {
        
        Name= "test_vpc"

     }
     
 }
```

Output.tf in VPC module

```
 output "vpc_id" {

    value= aws_vpc.main
}
```

variable.tf in subnet module

```
 variable "vpc_id" {

    type = string
}
```

subnets.tf in subnet module

```
resource "aws_subnet" "terraform_pub_sub"{


    cidr_block              = var.public_subnet_cidr_block
    availability_zone       = "us-east-1a"
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true
    vpc_id=var.vpc_id


  tags = {
    Project = "terra_tutorial"
  }
}
```

Terraform provider.tf

```
  provider "aws" {

    region = var.region
}

module "vpc_module"{

    source="./modules/network/vpc"
    vpc_name= "test_vpc"
    vpc_cidr_block="172.17.32.0/19"

}

module "subnet_module"{

    source = "./modules/network/subnets"
    public_subnet_cidr_block ="172.17.1.0/24"
    vpc_id= module.vpc_module.vpc_id
    
}
```

After running terraform plan following error is giving

```
 Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on providers.tf line 18, in module "subnet_module":
  18:     vpc_id= module.vpc_module.vpc_id

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "vpc_id" defined at
modules\network\subnets\variables.tf:3,1-18: string required.
```

How can I assign value to vpc_id using module? if output is returning object how can I get vpc_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the output from this:

```
output "vpc_id" {
    value= aws_vpc.main
}
```

to this:

```
output "vpc_id" {
    value= aws_vpc.main.id
}
```